# Как ограничить количество карточек приходящих по АПИ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Делаю сейчас приложение на реакте и тс в котором на страницу приходят данные по АПИ о криптовалюте и у меня из них получается список, в юрл я указал что **per_page=30** - значит придут данные на 30 монет. У меня задача сделать так чтоб рендерилось изначально 15 монет и когда пользователь проскролит вниз была кнопка по-типу "Показать еще" и при клике на нее отобразились еще 15... Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Может через useState при нажатии на кнопку "показать еще" увеличивать "per_page=30" ?

Comment: На сервере через пагинацию выводить следующие 15 элементов. На клиенте завести массив, при инициализации записать первые 15 элементов. Создать переменную с текущей страницей. При нажатии на кнопку "показать ещё" увеличивать страницу на 1, получат данные со следующей страницы и конкатенировать их в массив. И так, пока страницы не закончатся (для этого нужно возвращать количество страниц и проверять текущую с количеством).

Comment: Увеличивать `per_page` не вариант, так у Вас с каждым запросом будет тянуться всё больше даных с повторением, перерендеривать все блоки после получения данных таким способом тоже не очень хорошо.

Comment: @Somebody Не видя код и не зная возможности АПИ довольно сложно предложить варианты. АПИ может возвращать данные с X по Y позицию? При скролле можно ли понять на какой позиции пользователь? Сколько времени занимает ответ от АПИ? Сколько максимальное количество строк в ответете?